# cURL request to site returns empty document

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https

I have the following cURL request but it doesn't return any results for that particular url?

```
$ch = curl_init("https://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

It only returns:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

for the record I'm running `php 5.2.5` with `(libcurl/7.16.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.3)`
Any ideas?

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* - Use TLS 1.0 or above; and use Server Name Indication (SNI).

Comment: @jww I have no idea what you have suggested. Any chance of showing with some code?

Comment: @jww tried your suggestion and it doesn't make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix by replacing a newer version of the following files into apache22\bin folder

libeay32.dll
libssh2.dll
ssleay32.dll

Answer (score 0):

`$str` is not defined, you want to echo `$result`.

So, just changed your last line to `echo $result` and it's working

Comment: sorry that was a typo in my post. Any ideas why Its returning no results?

Comment: It does return the full HTML content for me, what you see when you visit the same URL in your browser? I can see the page, and when running the code it prints the page's source

Comment: I'm running from localhost and when i view page source it only returns `<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>`